# Sample size calculations for a pair-dependent discrete outcome

Tags: sample-size, statistical-power, discrete-data, clinical-trials

How do we calculate sample sizes (and power) for an outcome that is discrete and is only measurable between two individuals of a group?

Suppose we have $n_A$ individuals in group A, and $n_B$ individuals in group B. The outcome we measure is the number of metabolites that are common between any two individuals within group A, or between any two individuals within group B. We end up with nice boxplots showing that the number of metabolites that are common to two individuals within group A is indeed higher than metabolites shared between any two individuals within group B.

So then the question is: what's the power for our study if we have 20 indivdiuals in group A and 20 individuals in group B, and similarly, how many individuals do we need in groups A and B if we want 80% power? Is there a formula or calculator of sorts for this?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are going to take all possible combinations of two people in group A and take the distribution of the number of metabolites shared by both people in a random pair of people from A, and compare that distribution to the distribution that you would get from the same statistic with group B, and show that a random pair of individuals in group A usually have more metabolites than a random pair of individuals in group B, regardless of how large is the average difference when group A pairs have more metabolites or when group B pairs have more metabolites? You will want the Wilcoxon rank sum test. I caution you in the interpretation of this highly non-parametric test. Just because group A pairs have more metabolites the majority of the time, group B pairs can still have a higher average number of metabolites, if the group B distribution is more skewed right.

With that out of the way, I don't think you can specify the power without specifying the underlying distribution of metabolites in the population of people who could end up in sample A and the population of people who could end up in sample B. I could give you the power if you made some simple assumptions about those distributions, but it would require more than the mean and variance, because the nature of non-parametric estimation is we start without assumptions about the distribution.  The test statistic is
$U=\underset{i=1}{\overset{n_A}{\sum}} \underset{j=1}{\overset{n_B}{\sum}} .5*(x_i \geq y_j)+.5*(x_i>y_j)-\frac{n_A*n_B}{2}$, where $x_i$ and $y_j$ are random pairs from groups A and B and $n_A$ and $n_B$ are the number of possible pairs from groups A and B, $\frac{20*19}{1*2}=190$.

To get the p-value, take $z=\frac{U}{\sigma_u}$, $\sigma_u=(\frac{n_1*n_2*(n_1+n_2+1)}{12})^{.5}$, because z is approximately standard normal.

Comment: Thanks @MCS! Let's suppose, for sake of argument, that they're both Poisson distributions with different lambdas. 

I tried reading but couldn't wrap my head around it since most power calculations I read are based on some variation of a t-test or assume the data's normal.